# if statements in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

Can you have an "if" statement within an "array" function?

```
 $my_array = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => 'bar',
    'lorem' => $lorem,
    if($z == 'z'){ 'ipsum' => $ipsum }
);
```

my question of course pertains to line 5, the 4th item in the array. It doesn't seem to want to work, is there a bettwe way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that.  Just add the `if` statement after.

```
$my_array = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => 'bar',
    'lorem' => $lorem
);

if($z == 'z'){
    $my_array['ipsum'] = $ipsum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator:

```
$my_array = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => 'bar',
    'lorem' => $lorem,
    'ipsum' => ($z == 'z') ? $ipsum : null
);
```

Which would give you an array element equal to `null` if the comparison was `false`

Comment: This may not work for what the OP wants.  The value may be `null`, but it's still set.

Comment: +1 this is usually the best approach, although there is a caveat: If you use an `if` statement after the array declaration and it *doesn't* match, the key will not be set at all. With the ternary approach, however, the key will exist. If you use `null` as the fallback value then `isset()` will still behave as you expect, but `array_key_exists()` will not.

Comment: Thanks both, I realise that, but it's an alternative way in support of the other answers and highlights a language feature many php devs aren't aware of, so I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, as I can't have ipsum set at all. But for my clarification; does the `?` basically mean 'then do' and the `:`: mean 'else do' ?

Comment: @AlexDemchak Yes it does, it's called the ternary operator and it's documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) - it's actually a fairly standard syntax available in many languages.

Comment: foreach() loops won't work as before. If the items are objects and methods are called on them, you'd end up with a fatal error.

Comment: @cleong You can still perform an `isset()` check in the loop before you try and do anything with the variable, but I admit it is a little counter intuitive. It really depends what you are doing with the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put an if statement in an array initiation, but you could do the following:

```
$my_array = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => 'bar',
    'lorem' => $lorem,
);
if($z == 'z'){ $my_array['ipsum'] = $ipsum; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with short version of if statement:

```
$my_array = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => 'bar',
    'lorem' => $lorem,
    'ipsum' => $z == 'z' ? $ipsum : null
);
```